# Prometheus Alerting on NodeClockNotSynchronising for VMs

Tags: linux, ntpd, prometheus

I'm trying to determine why this Alert (`NodeClockNotSynchronising`) is firing for a handful of VMs I've provisioned. (Not all just a few, which is strange)

According to the metrics that are exported, I'm seeing:

```
# HELP node_timex_sync_status Is clock synchronized to a reliable server (1 = yes, 0 = no).
# TYPE node_timex_sync_status gauge
node_timex_sync_status 0
```

I can ssh into one of the VMs and `ntpd` is running and the `date` command returns the correct time.

So digging into the `timex` collector [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/v1.0.0-rc.0/docs/TIME.md#timex-collector) and [code](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/v1.0.0-rc.0/collector/timex.go) here's what is "failing":

```go
    var syncStatus float64
    var divisor float64
    var timex = new(unix.Timex)

    status, err := unix.Adjtimex(timex)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to retrieve adjtimex stats: %w", err)
    }

    if status == timeError {
        syncStatus = 0
    } else {
        syncStatus = 1
    }
```

Since syncStatus is 0 the alert is being fired.  Doing some digging into the return codes of [adjtimex()](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/sys/timex.h.html) syscall:

```c
#define TIME_ERROR        5        /* clock not synchronized */
```

Why would the kernel return `TIME_ERROR` when `ntpd` is running and the clock is synchronized?  Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the ntpd you are running, the kernel time discipline is reporting an error.

See `man ntp_adjtime` for the API and related constants.

On Linux, this could either be from NTP or PPS. Let's assume NTP, and further assume the error status is `STA_UNSYNC`, unsynchronized. This is set at boot. And cleared if a system call is done with a [`ADJ_OFFSET` mode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.9/kernel/time/ntp.c#L281), in other words if a ntpd is attempting to gradually change the clock.  This not happening does not make sense, all clocks will be at least a little bit off.

Review your `/etc/ntp.conf`. Ensure it contains 4 or more sources via `server` or `pool` directives.   Delete any [undisciplined local clocks](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/UndisciplinedLocalClock), which begin with `server 127.127.1`. LOCL is obsolete, most server clocks are not amazing, and possibly the 0 offset is preventing the unsync from being cleared.

Restart `ntpd` and wait two minutes. Watch the offsets compared to the NTP servers with `ntpq -p`, or `chronyc sources -v`, should be single or double digit ms but not zero.

Double check the date. Try it without confusing time zones: `date --utc`

Comment: Yep, the `ntp.conf` seem to be different for the ones triggering this alert.  Thank you for you help, I appreciate it. I got this fixed but using the correct `server` source and restarted the `ntpd`

Comment: Good. This is a useful check if it caught non functional NTP configurations.

Answer (score 1):

For ntpd: run the ntpddeamon without the option -x

Edit the ntpd configuration file and remove the -x option

vi /etc/sysconfig/ntpd
Restart the ntpd.service

systemctl restart ntpd.service

For chronyd: add the option rtcsync in /etc/chrony.conf if it is not there (it is included in the default configuration).

systemctl restart chronyd.service

Allow sometimes, alert will be cleared.